# Change rows and columns in list views

Tags: 2010, list, list-view

I'm facing another strange issue from my users, who love Excel sheets. Can I transform / mix / change rows and columns in one list using only a views? Is it possible to make this view (or list):

[image]
... from this original one?

[image]

The original list has one row per day and three choice columns called System 1, 2 and 3. New view (or more likely new list) must have systems in one column, three rows per one day with  values from choice columns as "Contact".

Changing view styles will not help me, neither lookup column, because values are choices.

If it is really possible without Excel sheet to be attached, what is the best way to do it? Thank you for any clue.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really solve your problem directly but the usual way I see this addressed is to simply group the view based on the column in question, "System" in your case.  The presentation is a bit different but usually works for most people.

Comment: This can work in first case, but it will be result. The original list has separate column for each system and it cannot be grouped (no more than two cases).

Comment: In that case, a Calculated field for System based on System1, System2, System3 might be what you are looking for.  Here is a rather extreme example : http://kartickapur.wordpress.com/2007/11/12/using-calculated-field-%E2%80%93-nested-if-statement-in-sharepoint-list/